# How can I convert string to int

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get a variable from cookie.

This variables comes as `String`.

I need to convert it to `Int`.

When I do this:

```
 @price = cookies[:price].to_i
```

I get a `fixnum`.
I really need to convert it to `int`

Is possible do that?

Comment: Fixnum is integer

Comment: I know, but I need a Integer type

Answer (score 6):

`Fixnum` is the class for numbers of a specific size in Ruby (i.e. it is an `Int`).

> Holds Integer values that can be represented in a native machine word (minus 1 bit). If any operation on a Fixnum exceeds this range, the value is automatically converted to a Bignum.

When an integer is too large, it becomes a `Bignum`.

```
"1.1".to_i.class
=> Fixnum

"1.1".to_f.class
=> Float

"1.1".to_d.class
=> BigDecimal

"1111111111111111111".to_i.class
=> Fixnum

"11111111111111111111".to_i.class
=> Bignum
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html